# WP7 - Why are my bindings not firing when the windows back button is pressed?

Tags: data-binding, windows-phone-7, mvvm-light, back-button

Hopefully there is an obvious answer to this that my brain at 2am is not seeing (I'm basing this on the fact I can't find anyone else with the same problem).

When I press the "hardware/built in" back button on my windows phone 7 none of my bindings are re-evaluating. For example on my MainPage I have a button's "IsEnabled" bound to a bool property in my ViewModel that checks if a value is in isolated storage. In the emulator it starts as disabled (obviously).  I then navigate to another page and add the required value to isolated storage. When i press the hardware back button to return to the original page the binding does not get re-evaluated and my button remains disabled.

However if I go back to MainPage via code using the navigate method the binding gets re-evaluated and everything is good.

Any ideas as to why?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue sounds like the RaisePropertyChanged method isn't being raised by your MVVM Light ViewModel - if you're binding Get{} accessor of your IsEnabled property on the viewmodel directly to a value in IsolatedStorage, then the ViewModel isn't going to know that that underlying value has necessarily changed.

When you write the value to IsolatedStorage, you can use the Messenger interface in MVVM to notify the ViewModel-in-question that it should fire the RaisePropertyChanged() event for your model, and that will re-bind that property in your view.

Comment: Hmmm that was the initial thing I was going to try because basically I neeed to RaisePropertyChanged from a different ViewModel to the one that needs it.  I didn't though because the navigate worked whereas the back button did not plus I don't keep my ViewModels like in the standard MVVM-light implementation so I assumed it would not be there to recieve the message.  I will give it a try and let you know

Comment: Ok that worked but it leaves me with more questions.  Navigating to a View via code makes calls my ViewModel's constructor whereas going via the back button does not.  Why is this? Is WP7 somehow keeing a reference to my view and ViewModel? If so how do I dispose of the ViewModel when the view is navigated away from so i am not keeping large collections in memory?

Comment: Pressing the back button just seems to pop the original view up as it was.  My ViewModelLocator property that exposes the ViewModel is not even being hit when the back button is pressed.

Comment: All ViewModels in traditional MVVM Light implementations are static. They're only initialized once per application unless you've made some significant changes to the ViewModelLocator or aren't using it at all.

Comment: The way the back stack works is that it will try to pull the VisualState of your pages from a cache, so it won't necessarily refire all of the bindings appropriately. If the default back-stack behavior is causing some issues, you can handle the back-stack events and manually drive some of the binding behavior in your views. Using the messenger interface to pop binding / nav events is a relatively easy way to do this.

Comment: Thanks,  yeh I wrote my own viewmodel locator using ninject (just trying out different things).  It was the back stack behaviour giving me grief.

Answer (score 0):

When you use the `NavigationService.Navigate` method, you are actually performing a *forwards* navigation and a new instance of your page is created. When you press the hardware back button, a *backwards* navigation is performed and the previous page is re-displayed. Almost all of the time, what you get is a cached version of the original instance of the page.

You could re-evaluate any bindings in the `OnNavigatedTo` override for the page, but this introduces a fair bit of 'code smell'. As mentioned above, using the `Messenger` will enable you to update the associated view model, which will update the binding on the page.